# How to get an id of the user in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is actually very easy but yet I am confused how to do this:
I have Reseller that can request X-number of users to admin. So that value gets saved to database. Now when admin logs in he can see the requests of resellers. Like this :
[image: Requests]

Now Admin Can either approve or reject the request. If He approves the request the code creates users in users table mapped to that reseller. **The mapping is done with a unique field called Key** Now Creating users works perfectly but my problem is :

When I click on Approve it creates users but for only for the reseller wit id = 1.  I want to create something like when I click on first record it creates users for 1st reseller and when on 2nd same as above[This is as per the image]. 
This is my view:

```
<?php if(count($users)): foreach($users as $user): ?>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td><?php echo  $user->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $user->user_requested; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $user->key; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $user->date_requested; ?></td>
    <td><a href="reseller/create_user" class="btn btn-primary">Yes&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></td>
    <td><a href="reseller/change_status" class="btn btn-danger">No&nbsp<?php echo'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>';?></a></td>
    <td><a href="" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo  $user->status; ?></td>&nbsp</a></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">There are no new Requests.</td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**The Controller**

```
public function create_user()
{
    $this->load->model('more_m');
    $id= $this->session->userdata('id');
    $rajan =$this->more_m->get(array('user_requested',$id));
    $request=$rajan->user_requested;        

    $this->load->model('reseller_m');

    $query=$this->db->select('key');
    $query=$this->db->get('reseller');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->row_array();
        $key= $row['key'];
    }

    for($i=1; $i<=$request;$i++)
    {

        $userdata=array('key'=>$key);

        $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);

    }

    $this->load->model('more_m');
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->db->set('status', "'approved'",FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('user_request');

    redirect('admin/new_user');
}
```

My mistake is in controller where I define $id. As when admin logs in his id would be fetched I don't know how to fetch the id of the reseller as per the record.

Comment: Use button value attribute.

Comment: @Bugfixer And how do i do that

Comment: First tell me how you wanna do it. php or php+jquery?

Comment: @Bugfixer with php, i hope you got what i want?

Comment: I just want to create users for the reseller who's approve button is pressed so maybe i need to pass that in view?

Comment: <td><a href="reseller/create_user/<?php echo  $user->id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Yes&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></td>.pass id with button href.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91056/discussion-between-bugfixer-and-rajan).

Comment: @Rajan, your questions is bit vague and not completely clear in terms of relation between the admin account and reselelr account and there activities.

Comment: @Arpita i was confused in the passing the Id in url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its so simple with Codeigniter

What you have to do is pass the ID with the URL (You are wrong Use `base_url()`as well with the pointing controller)

ex `<td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>reseller/create_user/<?php echo $user->key; ?>"`

so now your URL looks like (assume id is equal to 2)

> `http://localhost/<path to project>/reseller/create_user/2`

so **in Controller**

```
function create_user($id)//So this know incoming Value to this
{
   //then in here
   echo $id; //this will show 2
   //Continue rest of your code with $id
}
```

Comment: this worked for me but i have a problem my code still creates the users for first reseller Is my code correct for inserting key in users table?

Comment: my url is now this:http://localhost/crm/admin/reseller/create_user/2 but users are created under 1st reseller

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna do it in php way,You can pass `key` in your url and get key in your controller using `$this->uri->segment(n)`

```
   <?php if(count($users)): foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td><?php echo  $user->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $user->user_requested; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $user->key; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $user->date_requested; ?></td>
        <td><a href="reseller/create_user/<?php echo  $user->key; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Yes&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></td>
        <td><a href="reseller/change_status" class="btn btn-danger">No&nbsp<?php echo'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>';?></a></td>
        <td><a href="" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo  $user->status; ?></td>&nbsp</a></td>
    </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">There are no new Requests.</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

If you want jquery+php than use ajax.

add value attr. to button pass your key.

```
<button id="some_id" value="YOURKEY">Click Me</button
```

This is your script to update :

```
<script> 
$('body').on('click',"#some_id", function(){ 
var key =$(this).attr("value"); 
//Now you got ur key you can use ajax to update and change location of page on success 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: this worked for me but i have a problem my code still creates the users for first reseller Is my code correct for inserting key in users table?